# Is there a web service that provides terrain type at lat/lon?

Tags: web-services, geolocation, gis

I'm wondering if there is a (free?) web service that will return the type of terrain at a specific latitude and longitude?

The most important data I'm interested in is whether the point is over water or over land.  It would also be useful if I could find out if the point is in an urban area, desert, or in the rainforest, etc.  I might be able to guess that based on average rainfall/temperature for a location, or doing a reverse geocode.

Comment: Similar question focused on the binary land-or-water question, but with lots of solutions of varying granularity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644452/verify-if-a-point-is-land-or-water-in-google-maps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org) database, 7.5 million locations including lat/long/elevation and type of each location (see dictionary [here](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/featureCodes_en.txt)).

Comment: GeoNames is pretty amazing. I can't imagine a free/cheap service much better than that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know any ready-to-use web service, but I imagine you could use data from [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org); if you are only interested in large bodies of water (e.g. be able to distinguish points in ocean), even the small [png2tileinfo file](http://trac.openstreetmap.org/browser/applications/rendering/png2tileinfo/) would be enough (having 2-bit information for every ~0,088° square). Otherwise, the whole rest of the precise data is available there, but some preprocessing of the huge amount of data would be needed.