# MapBox water/land detection

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, detection, mapbox

I am starting to use the [MapBox iOS SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk).

**Is there any possible way to query the MapView by a coordinate and get back the terrain-type (water, land) as a result?**

I've been reading the [API doc](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/api) for quite a while now, but could not figure it out.
I know that there are [(interim) solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644452/verify-if-a-point-is-land-or-water-in-google-maps) available to use a Google webservice, but I need this to work offline.

I am not bound to MapBox (but I like it) though, thank you for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to delve into runtime styling (see my other answer, false lead): very simple method using `mapView.visibleFeatures(at: CGPoint, styleLayerIdentifiers: Set<String>)` equivalent for javascript API is `queryRenderedFeatures`.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool)
{
    let features = mapView.visibleFeatures(at: mapView.center, styleLayerIdentifiers: ["water"])
    print(features)
}
```

Example output when moving around:

```
[]
[]
[]
[<MGLMultiPolygonFeature: 0x170284650>]
```

If empty result: no water, if polygon: water.

Comment: See also same for [android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42728928/4601340)

Comment: `visibleFeatures` means only get result for the *visible* result, right? What if I want to get features within certain distance which might be invisible?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be possible:

Found on https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.5.0/runtime-styling.html

There is the possibility of adapting the UI according to the position of the user (park, city, water, etc.) Unfortunately I don't know how! (will update as soon as I find out)

> **Map interactivity** You can customize the map to the point of having it respond dynamically based on the actions your users are taking.
>   Increase the text size of streets while a user is driving, emphasize
>   points of interest tailored to a user’s preferences, or change your UI
>   if users are at parks, trails, landmarks, or rivers.
>
> [UI GIF demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUPkp.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample code that can help you a little bit.
https://github.com/P0nj4/Coordinates-on-water-or-land

giving a coordinate, the app checks with google if it's land or water.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but a necessary feature of this mechanism is the offline usage, since this will be used on a sailboat where a fast enough internet connection is not provided to implement a routing algorithm against a webservice. I actually implemented it with OSM data. It works easily, in memory, and super fast. See my link in my above answer.