# Prevent user from adding markers on ocean/river in google map api v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have implemented a map using google map api v3, where users can add a marker dynamically and give their feedback through a form in infowindow which pop-up while adding the marker.

I want to prevent users from adding the marker on ocean/river area.

I have searched solution for this requirement and I got this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644452/verify-if-a-point-is-land-or-water-in-google-maps), unfortunately the html5 canvas method explained there was for static map but I need this for dynamic one.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

For oceans and seas
You can use elevation api as in this example:
[Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-simple)
For ocenas and sees it will return negative number but:

1. It's not 100% accurate. For some terrains near water it returns negative numbers
2. It doesn't work for lakes and rivers

Comment: Thanks,so somehow I can reduce the pins on oceans using the example you gave.
but still am looking for complete solution.