# Optimizing Geographic Center in Google Maps with Respect to Travel Time if it Lies Within Water

Tags: php, google-maps, optimization, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

So I calculated the geographic center of multiple points and now want to optimize the geographic center so that if it lies in a body of water I can find the land point that is still closest to the true center, but also the closest for the original points. I also need some help with detecting if the point is infact in water so if someone could include the google maps query code for that I would appreciate it greatly. I included my getdata.php page to show my calculations, and any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to this stuff so spelt out explanations may be needed but again thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good way with Google Maps API to know if a point is above water or not. To get the *closest* address (on land) for a point that is over water, you could use [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding). But to my experiment, sometimes the coordinates returned are not really the closest place on land, and this will not work for a point in the middle of the ocean.

For more information, you can check the following question and answers: [Verify if a point is Land or Water in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644452/verify-if-a-point-is-land-or-water-in-google-maps)

There is also a good webservice by Geonames that you can find here: http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html

Especially the *Find nearby* and *Extended Find nearby toponym / reverse geocoding* which returns the ocean name in case it's over an ocean/sea. Try to register an account to play with it, because the demo account is usually *over limit*.

Hope this helps.