# How to avoid land while adding points to polyline?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API to add a map to my website that controls the route of a sailor. The route points are added on the fly with javascript and they are not quite detailed, so sometimes I get a line crossing over land.

Is it possible to add points to a Polyline and automatically avoid passing through land?

Comment: Short answer: no. There is no way to know whether a point is on land or above water with Google Maps API. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22906947/1238965

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimizing Geographic Center in Google Maps with Respect to Travel Time if it Lies Within Water](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901016/optimizing-geographic-center-in-google-maps-with-respect-to-travel-time-if-it-li)