# Android Google Maps API v2 check land or water

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm working with Android Google Maps API v2. Is it possible to check if point (LatLng) is in water or land?

Comment: Maps V2 has no means of telling you if a point is over land or water. Whether there is some other Google API that could do this, I cannot say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, there is no direct API for this AFAIK.**

[Another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9644812/603270) pointed out two possible workarounds:

- You can use Google Maps Reverse Geocoding . In result set you can determine whether it is water by checking types. In waters case the type is natural_feature. See more at this link http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types.
- You can detect waters/lands by pixels, by using Google Static Maps. But for this purpose you need to create http service.

Answer (score 0):

In the years since the original question was asked, a direct API service was started called [IsItWater.com](https://isitwater.com) which will let you check if a lat/lon is on water or land, based on OpenStreetMap data:

### Request

```
curl 'https://isitwater-com.p.rapidapi.com/?latitude=41.9029192&longitude=-70.2652276&rapidapi-key=YOUR-X-RAPIDAPI-KEY'
```

### Response

```
{
    "water": true,
    "latitude": 41.9029192,
    "longitude": -70.2652276
}
```