# How to get the elevation of the complete sea floor?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on an application that uses javascript to display a map and a marker at some coordinates over the sea.
I want the application to move that marker according a certain path but I want it to be stopped when it touches the land.

I am already able to show the map, move the marker and get the elevation, 
but it turns out that I must do a lot of calls to the elevation service to make sure the marker doesn't go on land.
I thought of asking once for each point on earth and save it to a file but...  I am not confortable with that solution. ;-)

Would anyone have a suggestion on how to determine if the marker is still on water without performing all the calls to 
the elevation service that my tests had me to do ?

Would there be a way to download this data or another data source I could use to get a map of the sea floor ?

I don't need it to be real-time accurate, but just enough to know if, in average, there is 1 meter of water or 25 meters at a certain location.

Thanks for any help, 
Claude

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644452/verify-if-a-point-is-land-or-water-in-google-maps would probably be a good place to start.