# how to check a point is accessible through road (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps

i'm getting latitude and longitude of a location, I want to know the roads connecting to that location and whether it is land or water

I tried one google map api which is not helping to get the information i want.
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.7127,74.0059&sensor=true

Answer (score 0):

[Another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9644812/603270) pointed out two possible workarounds:

- You can use Google Maps Reverse Geocoding . In result set you can determine whether it is water by checking types. In waters case the type is natural_feature. See more at this link http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types.
- You can detect waters/lands by pixels, by using Google Static Maps. But for this purpose you need to create http service.

You can use the Google Maps Geocoding API which does exactly that: http://code.google.com/intl/da-DK/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding Take a look at the "Reverse Geocoding" section

Comment: i also need roads connecting to that location

Comment: You can use the Google Maps Geocoding API which does exactly that: http://code.google.com/intl/da-DK/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Take a look at the "Reverse Geocoding" section.

Comment: clicking on the link- http://code.google.com/intl/da-DK/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding gives 404 error

Comment: Try this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: i appreciate your effort, but those apis are used to get address_components of your points, i want the information about the connecting roads.If there are 2 roads i want both