# android google maps walking directions

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I am developing an android application using google maps api v2.
The problem is google maps shows directions depending upon the road routes even if it is a open ground.
For example, take these two LatLng 
LatLng1 : -33.891143, 151.224473
LatLng2 : -33.891580, 151.225336

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt0Ox.png

But I want to show a straight direction as it is an open ground. I am using JSON for fetching directions (transit, walking, driving) like 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-33.891143, 151.224473&destination=-33.891580, 151.225336&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=transit

Is there any way possible to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Google Maps just doesn't know that you can walk over.

[image]

a workaround would be to draw a [simple polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple) between the two points if they are [close to each other](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical), and if [they are both open ground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644452/verify-if-a-point-is-land-or-water-in-google-maps).