# How to accurate determine if point on Google Maps is a building?

Tags: google-maps

Is there any accurate method to determine what type of object placed in selected point on Google Maps? For example: building, road or lake.

Comment: First realize that a single point on a two-dimensional map can be more than just one of these. There are lakes with tunnels under them for instance.

Comment: @LinuxDisciple Ok, I understand it. I want to cut off areas where peoples can't walk

Comment: The closest thing that I can give is you can limit the points/coordinates that you are using in either land or water. You can verify that coordinates by following the answer and suggestion in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644452/verify-if-a-point-is-land-or-water-in-google-maps). With the help of this you can now know if that point is in the water area, then you can now limit that place in your project.

Comment: @KENdi Thank you, your link is very useful for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing that I can give is you can limit the points/coordinates that you are using in either land or water. You can verify that coordinates by following the answer and suggestion in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644452/verify-if-a-point-is-land-or-water-in-google-maps). With the help of this you can now know if that point is in the water area, then you can now limit that place in your project.