# Is possible to know if a point is land or sea?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

Is it possible to know if a point is a land or sea ?

I have searched many times but the only way could work is (or maybe **was** ?) using `Google Maps Reverse Geocoding` like suggest here: [Verify if a point is Land or Water in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644452/verify-if-a-point-is-land-or-water-in-google-maps)

Using this method i should have `natural_feature` but i think it doesn't work...
For example:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.6984,-74.0220

This a place, in sea, in front of Island Manhattan but in result i don't read "natural_feature".

Can you suggest a way to know if a point is sea or land ? (also using google maps API, javascript or PHP

Thanks a lot and sorry for my English

Comment: https://onwater.io/ ?

Comment: And why not try the second option proposed in the answer you linked?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type that you want the response to include by using the `result_type` parameter.

Here is an example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.6984,-74.0220&result_type=natural_feature
```

Unfortunately, for this parameter, you need an API key.

Comment: i add an api key and result is empy and "status": zero_results ?

Comment: @Borja Yes, I've just gave it a try myself and got 0 results. I'm not sure what is the cause.

Comment: Maybe is not accurate... :( Thanks

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17712290)

Comment: @DiskJunky The link is not the issue here.

Comment: @DiskJunky This is not a *link only answer*, it is an answer that explains how to generate a link to get a specific result. I didn't add the link to answer the question, I've added it to illustrate my explanation.

Comment: @Titus I'm in agreement, on closer inspection the flag is invalid. A moderator will see the comments and clear it. I do flag things but don't generally downvote so net effect is nil. It'll clear in the end.