# Detect water/sea between two lat longs

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

How can we detect is there any water/sea between two lat-longs using google map API or any PHP library.

e.g. In the attached image, there is water between Marker **H** and Marker **P** so somehow I want to know that yes there is water between this two lat-longs.

[image]

Note: It is different from [Verify if a point is Land or Water in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644452/verify-if-a-point-is-land-or-water-in-google-maps)

In my question I want to detect is there any water between two lat-longs, I don't want to know that my lat-long is on land or on water.

Comment: Can you check following question+answer if any valuable information is in there for you? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644452/verify-if-a-point-is-land-or-water-in-google-maps

Comment: This looks promising: http://tech.bellycard.com/blog/where-d-the-water-go-google-maps-water-pixel-detection-with-canvas/

Comment: The above technique has proved to work well for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verify if a point is Land or Water in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644452/verify-if-a-point-is-land-or-water-in-google-maps)