# Find a point(LatLng) X meter/km away from pickup point(LatLng) and should not be in Water(Sea)

Tags: android, google-maps

I have to draw a curve line on google map from a selected known point (LatLng) to a distance of like 200meters. The point (LatLng) after 200m should not be in Water(Sea). So,

How to:

**1. Find the other point(LatLng) in 200m from pickup point.**

**2. The point(LatLng) should not be in water(sea).**

[image]

**Edited question:**

Please ignore the 'curve line'. It can be a straight line, main problems are the 2 points that I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

This is an incomplete answer to a somewhat ambiguous question.

You indicate "curve line" but don't specify the curve function so it's impossible to provide help specifically on that.

If by "curve line" you mean circle around a point then you may be interested in the SphericalUtil class in the [android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) which provides for finding "offsets" (`computeOffset`) from a point - but this assumes a circle from a center point - which is difficult to apply to your unknown curve function.  And ofcourse the map itself provides for `addCircle`.

Also, to determine if any one point on the Earth's surface is in water you can use Google Maps Reverse Geocoding as in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9644812/2711811 . It mentions using 'type' field which is 'natural_feature' for water.

But this answer leaves open the general issue of "how to find a point not in water 200 meters from a center point" without an indeterminate, iterative approach - (i.e. keeping picking random points until not in water - which fails if the center point is on a 150-meter island).  To solve this you'd have to limit your point space to land which means having knowledge of land/sea.

Example random point at 200 meters from center point:

```
SphericalUtil.computeOffset(pickupPoint, 200, new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextDouble * 360)
```

Feel free to add more detail to your question.

Comment: Please ignore the 'curve line' in the question It can be a straight line. The main problem is to **find a point from a known point at the distance of 200m** and **That point should not be in water.**